# корректная работа функции с указателем

Tags: c, массивы, функции, указатели

Имеется следующая функция:

```
void func(int *arr, int *p) {
     /* код, в процессе которого узнаётся значение count и массива 
        arr_temp; его размер - count */
     p = (int*)realloc(count * sizeof(int));
     memset(p, 0, count * sizeof(int));
     memcpy(p, arr_temp, count);
     for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
          printf("%d ", p[i]);  
}

void main()
{
     int *p;
     int temp[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
     /* без инициализации передать указатель в функцию нельзя: компилятор 
        ругается */
     p = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
     memset(p, 0 , sizeof(int));
     func(temp, p);
}
```

Проблема в том, что если выводить на экран значение массива `arr_temp`, то то выведутся все корректные элементы. Если же выводить элементы массива `p`, то выведутся только первые 4 элемента массива `arr_temp`, а остальные будут нулями. Подскажите, что я не так делаю?

Comment: 1. Функция `main` должна возвращать `int`; 2. Функции `realloc` в качестве первого аргумента надо передавать указатель, а вторым аргументом новый размер; 3. Вместо связки `malloc` + `memset` используйте `calloc`; 4. Приведение типа `(int*)` делать не надо; 5. Не забывайте вызывать `free`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 memcpy(p, arr_temp, count);
```

Это - запись из `arr_temp` в `p` ровно `count` **байт**, а вовсе не `int`'ов...

Странно, что в `memset` вы указали размер верно, как `count*sizeof(int)`, а тут - нет.

Comment: невнимательность с моей стороны!
Спасибо большое :)